# Kernel Panic with Buildroot Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, buildroot, panic

I (try to) make a complete minimal Kodi Linux system with buildroot from scratch, everything compiles fine and i also got it to boot but after some lines of console output and graphics reset it gives me a kernel panic error:

```
at arch/x86/kernel/smp.c:128 native_smp_send_reschedule+0x33/0x40
```

I have no clue why...

My buildroot config file: https://pastebin.com/7PC4zLEa

Image from the kernel panic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2u8q.jpg

Comment: Or is the real problem in mount_root() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that im just a bit ..., i forgot that there is a inbuilt hdd. I had sda2 in GRUB configured but i had to use sdb2.
Hope this helps someone.